# change language apk failed

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I want to change the language of an application which is in English. I created a strings.xml and values-fr file but when I launch the app it stays in English. AND when I replace the original strings with the FR directly recompil failed.How I can do

thanks

Comment: Can you please add version and code example?

Comment: its a screen https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/16/4/1587027630-sans-titre.jpg

Comment: This sounds correct. Android will use the language which is set in the phone settings. English speaking users get the English texts. French users the French text.

Comment: yes but when i load apk on my french phone , its english text... But i don't know where i can find the files who i have to changer the local files FR

Answer (score 0):

You have update the application Locale and Configration , example is given below how to set the app Locale.

```
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return context;

   }
```

Like in your case you can set it as -

```
updateResources(this, "fr")
```

Comment: I did not do it. In which folder are these lines? I begin.. Asset, lib, original,res ;smali ? thanks

Comment: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/16/4/1587027671-sans-titre2.jpg its a screen ; where find this code ,whats files ?